# How to get xml page by url

Tags: java, xml-parsing

Ok, so I got some url link like https://stackoverflow.com/ and I'm trying to parse it in document  but getting error. Why? Because this is not xml file, so the question is how can I get data as xml if i got only url? 
My code:

```
public class URLReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {


// or if you prefer DOM:
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = db.parse(new URL("https://stackoverflow.com/").openStream());
        int nodes = doc.getChildNodes().getLength();
        System.out.println(nodes + " nodes found");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To parse HTML you may use JSOUP: https://jsoup.org/

This library provides also some features to transform HTML to XHTML, which some sort of XML:

```
Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);
document.outputSettings().syntax(Document.OutputSettings.Syntax.xml);  
document.outputSettings().escapeMode(org.jsoup.nodes.Entities.EscapeMode.xhtml);
String xhtml=document.html();
```

Comment: how to get html? and also why OutputSettings is not a proper func in my project after imlementing JSOUP?

Comment: Maybe you are using the wrong ```Document```class. You need to use ```org.jsoup.nodes.Document```. You cannot parse HTML with classes like ```DocumentBuilder``` that are made for XML only. If you simply want to download any file from an URL, then forget all that parsing stuff and use ```URLConnection``` instead or the Apache HttpClient, see https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html